# About including offensive terms in posts

Tags: discussion

This sprung up in effect to [this answer post](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/78099/40592). (I've just edited it)

The original post contained some inappropriate words to what seems against our [*'be nice'*](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy. Apart from those words, the post did contain some useful content. Hence, I made the edit censoring those terms instead of raising a flag.

What should be done in this sort of situation?

Answer (score 9):

Your edits replaced "piss him off" with "annoy him" and "put him off". You also changed "beer/sweets" to just "sweets".

I do not think beer is an offensive term to anyone and it provides more information than just sweets. In regards to "piss him off" this was not used as an insult. Presumably, you replaced it because you think it is a "curse". I think that is a stretch, but not completely unreasonable. I would avoid using *pissed* while teaching, but would use it while talking to colleagues. There is also the issue of UK/US meaning. Pissed in the UK means drunk while pissed in the US means annoyed. Curses in answers has been discussed before

[What does the offensive flag mean to you](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1160/what-does-the-offensive-flag-mean-to-you)

[Are expletives (cursing, swear words or vulgar language) allowed on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites)

As for what to do, if you see something you think is not nice edit it. If you want confirmation, ask on meta or chat. You can ask either before or after acting. You could also flag the content, but I would reserve this for bigger infractions.

Comment: Thanks for the additional references. About the UK and US meanings, they are both the same under the given context. The 'drunk' aspect is just an additional meaning that I believe is rarely used.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac Beer is definitely not offensive... and many of us would certainly prefer beer over sweets ;-) (and notice that in many countries alcohol is allowed on the university premises and can be found in the university cafeterias).

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac I know this is getting off topic, but I can assure you that the `drunk' meaning of that verb/adjective is most definitely still used and commonly understood in the UK.